# Wait until unknown number of $.get are completed, then refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am running a piece of javascript to run an Ajax call (returned as XML), process that XML and then do another Ajax call for each "record" found in the XML (deletes the record), then once all things have been completed, refresh the page.

This works fine but I can't get the Javascript to wait until all of the iterative Ajax calls have completed before refreshing the page.

What is the best way to wait until all of the iterative calls are completed before refreshing the page?

Any "AVMI_" variable is defined elsewhere.

```
var x = $.get(AVMI_childDB, {   //******* INITIAL AJAX *******
    act: "API_DoQuery",
    query: AVMI_query, 
    clist: "3",
    includeRids: "1"
});

x.then(function(xml1) {
    console.dirxml(xml1);
    $(xml1).find('record').each(function(){
        var AVMI_record = $(this); 
        var AVMI_childRID = AVMI_record.attr("rid");
        console.log(AVMI_childRID);
        var y = $.get(AVMI_childDB , {   //******* ITERATIVE AJAX CALL ******* 
            act: 'API_DeleteRecord', 
            rid: AVMI_childRID
        });
        y.then(function(xml2) {
            console.dirxml(xml2);
        });
    });
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: You could use the first request to store a variable count of how many records were found, then on every completion up the count. If the current count +1 equals your previous count, refresh.

Comment: I think I could probably do it this way too, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect each promise you create in your loop and then you can use `$.when()` to know when they are all done:

```
var x = $.get(AVMI_childDB, {   //******* INITIAL AJAX *******
    act: "API_DoQuery",
    query: AVMI_query, 
    clist: "3",
    includeRids: "1"
});

x.then(function(xml1) {
    console.dirxml(xml1);
    var promises = [];
    $(xml1).find('record').each(function(){
        var AVMI_record = $(this); 
        var AVMI_childRID = AVMI_record.attr("rid");
        console.log(AVMI_childRID);
        var y = $.get(AVMI_childDB , {   //******* ITERATIVE AJAX CALL ******* 
            act: 'API_DeleteRecord', 
            rid: AVMI_childRID
        }).then(function(xml2) {
            console.dirxml(xml2);
        });
        promises.push(y);
    });
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        location.reload();
    })

});
```

It might be a little cleaner to use `.map()` and let jQuery collect the promises for you:

```
var x = $.get(AVMI_childDB, {   //******* INITIAL AJAX *******
    act: "API_DoQuery",
    query: AVMI_query, 
    clist: "3",
    includeRids: "1"
}).then(function(xml1) {
    console.dirxml(xml1);
    var promises = $(xml1).find('record').map(function(){
        var AVMI_record = $(this); 
        var AVMI_childRID = AVMI_record.attr("rid");
        console.log(AVMI_childRID);
        return $.get(AVMI_childDB , {   //******* ITERATIVE AJAX CALL ******* 
            act: 'API_DeleteRecord', 
            rid: AVMI_childRID
        }).then(function(xml2) {
            console.dirxml(xml2);
        });
    }).get();
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        location.reload();
    })

});
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  What is incorrect about this answer?  It shows a more complete solution than the other answer and consistently uses jQuery for the promise management so it would work even in older browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had done some research and had basically settled on doing it the way you have done in your first example but couldn't quite write it out. Your answer has solved my issue and has allowed me to move forward with other similar tasks! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Since each .get() returns a promise, I suggest you push these promises into an array.  Then at the end of your function you can simply do `Promise.all(myArrayOfPromises).then(refreshThePage)`